# Java program that access C++ shared library that uses OpenCV

Tags: java, c++, opencv, makefile, compilation

We developed a C++ shared library (`libAuxLinuxShared.so`), that uses OpenCV 2.4

We also developed a command-line Java app that access `libAuxLinuxShared.so` via JNI.
This app is deployed in Ubuntu 14.10

When running the Java app, we're getting the following result:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /vagrant/Milan/Linux/libAuxLinuxShared.so: /vagrant/Milan/Linux/libAuxLinuxShared.so: undefined symbol: _ZTVN2cv12_OutputArrayE
    at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1941)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1857)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1122)
    at com.mi.pixme.PixmeJavaAPI.<clinit>(PixmeJavaAPI.java:8)
    at com.mi.pixme.PixmeCommandRunner.main(PixmeCommandRunner.java:11)
```

It appears to me that OpenCV is not linked properly when making `libAuxLinuxShared.so`, or that the OpenCV shared libraries cannot be found. I'm not a C++ expert, certainly not under Linux, and I'm not sure what to do next.

### Some more details

I tried to do this in two ways:

1. Make OpenCV as shared libraries
2. Make OpenCV as static libraries, and try to link `libAuxLinuxShared.so` with them (with -l).
   I use `pkg-config --libs --cflags opencv` in the Makefile in order to get the complete list of libraries.

In both cases I get the same result.

It may be helpful to note that the result of:

```
$ nm -D libAuxLinuxShared.so | grep _ZTVN2cv12_OutputArrayE
```

Is:

```
U _ZTVN2cv12_OutputArrayE
```

even when I try to do static linking of OpenCV.
The symbol is probably defined in the `opencv_core` library:

```
$ nm /usr/local/lib/libopencv_core.so | grep _ZTVN2cv12_OutputArrayE
00000000004b1de0 V _ZTVN2cv12_OutputArrayE
```

I also tried setting `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib:/usr/local/share/OpenCV/3rdparty/lib` (which is where the OpenCV libs are located), but the result was the same.
One last thing I tried was to load the `opencv_core` shared libary (where I think `_ZTVN2cv12_OutputArrayE` is located) from the Java app:

1. Added to the Java main class:

   System.loadLibrary("opencv_core");
2. And then adding `/usr/local/lib` to the library path of the Java command, like this:

   -Djava.library.path=/usr/local/lib:.

But again, same results. I can see that the Java program finds the library, because if I change `opencv_core` to some name that doesn't exist, I get a different error (that the library can't be found).
But when the library name is correct, it has no effect on the results, which is the exception complaining the _ZTVN2cv12_OutputArrayE is not defined.

**Edit:**
The following gist contain the makefiles I use for building the shared library:
https://gist.github.com/yanivby/69984a541e97e33d815a76a9bbf4d712

Comment: Hey, please run `ldd /vagrant/Milan/Linux/libAuxLinuxShared.so` and post the output. I think this may have something to do with `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, but I'm not sure what good it would do to set the environment variable when loading from Java (not to mention if the Java process itself doesn't have the variable set properly).

Comment: @YamMarcovic, it would be great if you publish your answer here to get the credit.

Comment: Sure, but you should add a link to your gist Makefiles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the Makefiles in your gist, the problem seems to be that the `pkg-config --libs --cflags opencv`, which adds a bunch of `-l library` arguments to the linker, is mentioned *before* the objects that actually depend on those libraries. In your Makefile, the easiest fix would be to move your `$(INCLUDES)` reference to the end of the commands, after `$(LIBS)`.

Comment: Could you please be more precise? I have no access to that gist link to see the Makefiles. Thank you